# How do handle filename space and Character with FIND command

Tags: bash, find

Good day all,
I am working on a bash script to merge multiple mp3 files to one. The code is working fine but cannot handle file name with space or Characters. Below is the code. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

```
for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0 | xargs -0 ); do
  ffmpeg -i "concat:intro.mp3|"$file"|outro.mp3" -acodec copy "${file%.mp3}-".mp3;
done
```

Comment: note that $file is outside double quotes inner double quotes must be removed, otherwise argument for a file with a space will be split

Comment: See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Answer (score 2):

read builtin with `-d` followed by empty argument to use NUL caracter as input record delimiter

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    ffmpeg -i "concat:intro.mp3|$file|outro.mp3" -acodec copy "${file%.mp3}-".mp3;
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0)
```

Comment: Thanks, Nahuel. I ran the command but didn't perform any action

Comment: `: do something with "$file"`  has to be changed by actual command needed

Comment: Yes, I did so 
 `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    : do ffmpeg -i "concat:intro.mp3|"$file"|outro.mp3" -acodec copy "${file%.mp3}-".mp3;
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0)`

Comment: also as told in quastion's comment inner quote around `$file` make it outside quotes : argument should be `"concat:intro.mp3|$file|outro.mp3" `

Comment: i just seen your comment (`:` is a no-op, i could also use `#`) just `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do  ffmpeg -i ...` but because it was not clear i'm updating

Answer (score 2):

find has an `-exec` flag that allows you to call scripts with the search results.

e.g. creating a simple helper-script addxtros.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
infile=$1
outfile=${infile%.mp3}-.mp3 
ffmpeg -i "concat:intro.mp3|${infile}|outro.mp3" -acodec copy "${outfile}"
```

you can use it like:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec ./addxtros.sh {} ";"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` together with `bash -c` command (that allows passing 2 arguments to `ffmpeg`):

```
 find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "concat:intro.mp3|$1|outro.mp3" -acodec copy "${1%.mp3}-.mp3"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks
I got this `find: missing argument to `-exec'
`